# FBSession SDK helpers debugging

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to create helpers to authenticate and request publish permissions for Facebook. Facebook has a really confusing API, such as `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]`, where `completionHandler` is not what you would think. `completionHandler` is confusingly called every time the session state changes, not when `openActiveSession` completes.

My flow is pretty straightforward. The issue is I sporadically get those common FBSession errors, like `FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize permissions on an unopened session`.

Can anyone tell me what I might possibly be doing wrong?

```
- (void)openSessionWithBasicInfoThenRequestPublishPermissions:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    [self openSessionWithBasicInfo:^(NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            completionBlock(error);
            return;
        }

        [self requestPublishPermissions:^(NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionBlock(error);
            });
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)openSessionWithBasicInfo:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    if([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
        completionBlock(nil);
        return;
    }

    self.openBlock = completionBlock;

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error open:YES permissions:NO];
        });
    }];
}

static NSString *const publish_actions = @"publish_actions";

- (void)requestPublishPermissions:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    if([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions] indexOfObject:publish_actions] != NSNotFound) {
        completionBlock(nil);
        return;
    }

    self.permissionsBlock = completionBlock;

    [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[publish_actions] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:session.state error:error open:NO permissions:YES];
        });
    }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error open:(BOOL)open permissions:(BOOL)permissions
{
    if(self.openBlock && open) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.openBlock(error);
            self.openBlock = nil;
        });
    }
    else if(self.permissionsBlock && permissions) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.permissionsBlock(error);
            self.permissionsBlock = nil;
        });
    }
}
```

My goal with the completion blocks is not for them to be called every time the session state changes, but single use blocks where I open a session and say post on the user's wall on completion. This is why I store the blocks on a property and then nil them out after they are used.